# List of wireless adapters compatible with Windows 10 “Projecting to this PC”

Tags: windows-10-mobile, windows-10

I tried to use this feature to project my Lumia 950 on 2 computers: one with a Intel® Centrino® Advanced-N 6235 and one with a Netgear WNA1100 and none of them worked.
Do you know of any wireless card/chipset that work 100%? In particular I'd need a Usb wireless adapter.

Answer (score 0):

- Intel 7260 mini-pci
- Intel 8260 NGFF (I used 2 adapters ngff -> mini-pci-x -> pci-x)

Still looking for a USB solution